# Read a text file in R and manipulating data

Tags: r

I would like some help with reading data in text file and manipulating data. Below is the code to read all the columns in the file.

```
fileName <- ("Data_10_04_2020.csv")    
conn <- file(fileName,open="r")    
linn <-readLines(conn)    
for (i in 1:length(linn)){    
  print(linn[i])    
}
```

I want to read one column of that file and if any value in that column and replace with null value

Ex: if any value in email column then replace with null value

Sample file layout:

```
ID,Name,email
10,Ravi,test@gmail.com
20,Sunil,abc@gmail.com
```

Any help much appreciated

Comment: What aren't you using something like `read.csv()` to read in this data? That will parse all the columns for you. Then you can just set all values of email to NA for missing (you can't store nulls in a column in R)

Comment: how do i set all the values of email to NA or would it be possible to do the data masking in R?

Comment: After you read the data in, just do `mydata$email<-NA`. Use whatever variable name you saved the data as.

Comment: Thank you, 
I did try with below, how do I write all the data back to a different file with the updated email addresses values ?
Credit_tbl <-read.csv(file = 'Survey_Data_10_04_2020.csv',sep = ",")

Credit_tbl$Email_Address<-'NA'%>% select(Email_Address)

Comment: Use `write.csv()` to write out an updated CSV file.

Comment: sorry for the 2 many questions as I'm new to R
if i want to add another column to set NA, how do i modify the below ? do i need to use a another variable 
Credit_tbl1$conact_no<-'NA'?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211595/discussion-between-npk-and-mrflick).